# How to use openssl from external directory in my native application (c++) in android

Tags: android, encryption, openssl

I want to encrypt data in my program with aes. The aes implementation inside openssl in android kind of suits my needs. What are the necessary codes that i have to add in Android.mk of my application.

All I want to do is something like this:

```
uint8_t data[16];
AES_KEY AESKey;
AES_encrypt(data, data, AESKey);
```

thank you

Comment: You are probably better served by bundling your own copy of OpenSSL in with your app, for consistency. SQLCipher for Android recently moved to that: http://sqlcipher.net/blog/2013/8/28/sqlcipher-for-android-222-release.html

Comment: I managed to have a copy of aes source file (along with the header) and achieved my goal :)